# Import svg file in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, svg, import

I have several SVG files and want to create one SVG file. According to their file, they all should have a size of 22x22 Pixels. If I open one of those SVG files (or import it), there will be a rectangle with the size of 22x22 Pixels and the actual object (icon) will be smaller. So I suppose, Inkscape somehow deletes the white space surrounding the object.

How can I achieve that when I import a SVG file, its size is actually 22x22 pixel? For example with this [icon](https://github.com/PapirusDevelopmentTeam/papirus-icon-theme/blob/master/Papirus/22x22/panel/battery-caution.svg). Currently the icon has something about 10x14 Pixels if I import it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the size in Inkscape. It is the page size which is 22px x 22px, but the object itself is only 10px x 14px.

[image]

When you import the image into Inkscape, that is in fact the correct size. Inkscape isn't deleting anything when you import. There is no "white space". You are merely importing the 10xp x 14px object into a different sized page. Inkscape does not support multi-page documents currently.

A possible workaround is to create a 22px x 22px square around the page, set the fill and stroke to none, then with the square still selected, switch to the Select and Transform Objects tool (F1), then while holding down the Shift key, also select the top and bottom part of the object, then Group (Ctrl+G).  Then when you import it, you will be importing a 22px x 22px invisible square along with the graphic.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your answer really helped a lot!

Comment: Just for all the people having not so much experience with Inkscape like me: Create a new rectangle, make it invisible (color panel at the bottom), switch to Select and Transform Objects tool (shortcut: f1), the rectangle should be still selected, now you can change x and y to zero at the top (origin) and w and h to 22 at the top of Inkscape. The actual object should be  centered in the 22x22 Pixel rectangle now. Now just hit Ctrl+A (which will select all element) and press Ctrl+G to group them. By this you can have the white space in about 10sek, even without much experience with Inkscape

Comment: @Leon0402 Yup, you got it!